# Not able to write SQL Queries

Tags: mysql

Customer

```
ID  (integer)   Name (Varchar)
10001   Akash Kumar
10002   Vijay Chopra
10003   Rahul Mishra
```

Transactions

```
ID  (integer)   CUST_ID(integer)    STOCK_SYM(varchar)  TYPE(varchar)   QTY(integer)
1   10001   UNITECH BUY 100
2   10003   UNITECH SELL    200
3   10001   DLF BUY 500
4   10001   DELTA   BUY 450
5   10002   DLF BUY 110
6   10002   DLF SELL    400
```

I want to Show the stock with their total shares traded greater than 300.

I also want to Display maximum quantity BOUGHT by each customer along with customer’s name.
Can anyone tell the query i should use.

Comment: any try for this from your side ?? looks like a total surrender..look for `Joins` `Aggregate Functions`, `Group By/ Order By` etc ....just make some efforts on your own :)

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: I am really lost with it.

Comment: It it not so complicated as you think. Try to do it yourself.

Comment: @CORRUPT: It is not complicated indeed. Why did you vote to migrate this to DBA.SE then? SQL questions are fine there, but only [*advanced* SQL ones](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please consider that for the future.

Answer (score 7):

This shows the MAX only where the SUM is more then 300

```
SELECT
    C.Name, X.SumQty, X.MaxQTY
FROM
    Customer C
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        CUST_ID, SUM(QTY) AS SumQty, MAX(QTY) AS MaxQTY
    FROM
        Transactions
    GROUP BY
        CUST_ID
    HAVING
        SUM(QTY) > 300
    ) X ON C.CUST_ID = X.CUST_ID;
```

To show MAX for all customers, not just where the total is >300, then it is 2 queries but these can be worked out from my one here